# Capturing data based on index

Tags: c#

I have developed a program to read through text in files and capture information, and write it into a CSV.

Each "field" is identified by an index, a label, and a value, like so:

> .0 index
>   .0.label unicode "Area"
>   .0.value unicode "6WAY DB"
>   .1 index
>   .1.label unicode "SubStation"
>   .1.value unicode "E782DB257"
>   .2 index
>   .2.label unicode "MCC ID"
>   .2.value unicode ""
>   .3 index
>   .3.label unicode "Feeder"
>   .3.value unicode ""
>   etc...

In this CSV, I capture the "label" as a column header, then the "value" as the data for each record - simple enough. However, the situation begins to get complex when some files have different information - different labels especially.

Creating the header row isn't such a difficult thing, but making sure the data is captured correctly is a different matter. For example,

File A:

> .0 index
>   .0.label unicode "Area"
>   .0.value unicode "6WAY DB"

File B:

> .0 index
>   .0.label unicode "SubStation"
>   .0.value unicode "110"

That means I need to somehow identify that even though these are the first items in each file, I need to identify these as separate fields. I was thinking of using index tags as a part of building the column header row, or even using the labels as tags for each field, so that they can be entered in the correct order?

For example, I would build the column header like so:

```
[0: Area, 1: Equipment, …]
```

Then when reading through the file, use that to identify the appropriate location for each field

```
filename | Area    | SubStation | Other
File A   | 6WAY DB | E782DB257  |
File B   |         | 110        |
etc...
```

Can/should I use arrays for this? or is there a batter way to capture this information?

Comment: Since you are the one writing this CSV, might I suggest that your problem would be easier to solve if you wrote it using a better data format?  The format that you've illustrated in your last example would be much easier to read, if you just wrote it that way from the  start.

Comment: You can have a dictionary with a string-based field name as key, and the dictionary's value is another dictionary. You can also have a dictionary whose key is a composite, i.e. the key itself consists of a tuple, and its GetHashCode and Equals methods have been overridden to take into account each of the tuple's components.